How to communicate between background.js and content.js?
I want to communicate between content.js and background.js, but it doesn't work. There are no errors, and I can communicate between popup.js and background.js normally.
Here is my manifest.json:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["sounds/test.mp3"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting",
    "webNavigation",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icons/16.png",
      "48": "icons/48.png",
      "128": "icons/128.png"
    }
  }
}

Here is background.js:
console.log("BACKGROUND: Playing 60 second audio");
// This works and prints the code in extension console

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'playAudio', data: "test.mp3"}); 

Here is content.js:
console.log("Loading content");

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log("Message received in content script:", message);
    if (message.action === 'playAudio') {
      switch(message.data) {
        case "test.mp3":
          const test = new Audio(chrome.runtime.getURL('sounds/test.mp3'));
          console.log("Playing test");
          test.play();
          break;
      }}
});

The extension console prints the console.log, and the website console prints the first line when loading content.js, however, the communication between them doesn't seem to be working. This works between popup.js, which I use for the popup itself, and background.js. The code is more or less the same there. What am I missing here?
I tried adding a lot of permissions. I tried changing from chrome.runtime to chrome.tabs, chrome.extension. I tried creating a new simple project with only the communication. I looked at other stackoverflow posts but none answer this question, at least for my specific case. I asked ChatGPT but everything it says doesn't work.

This is because background.js sends the request before content.js waits for the request to be received.

@NorioYamamoto I tried also attaching the sendMessage from background.js to a timer, as well as a button click. I put a console.log("Content loaded") after the listener, and only clicked the button after it was printed in console. The console.log in background.js within the button click went off, but the communication seemingly didn't happen as there was no print of the console.log for receiving a message in content.js

If you want to send to tabs you need to use chrome.tabs.sendMessage.

Here is a sample of it.
manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}

background.js
console.log("BACKGROUND: Playing 60 second audio");

const main = async () => {
  tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  if (tabs.length == 0) {
    console.log("There is no active tab.");
  }
  else if (tabs[0].url.indexOf("chrome") == 0) {
    console.log("A tab in which content scripts cannot be injected is active.");
  }
  else {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: 'playAudio', data: "test.mp3" });
  }
}

setInterval(main, 3000);

content.js
console.log("Loading content");

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log("Message received in content script:", message);
});

